# Can an CSV file be converted to graph using GraphX in Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I am new to Spark. I found all the implementations of graphs using the Apache Spark GraphX library to be in Scala. Can someone help me with the implementation in **Java?** The Java APIs are not so descriptive and I am not able to figure out how to load a graph from a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no Java API for GraphX yet, so you will need to stick with Scala. A [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3665) was created last year to add a Java API, but it won't be released until Spark 1.5.0.

Comment: Though it is still possible to use GraphX Scala API in Java application... but it is rather verbose.